# didFinishLaunchingWithOptions not called

Tags: iphone, xcode4, push-notification

I'm having trouble enabling push notifications.

with this code I try to enable the notification:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationType)(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    return YES;
}
```

It doesnt work, so I added a breakpoint in the line

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationType)(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

But it seems this part of the code is never execute.

why is this not working?

Comment: Try resetting the simulator, deleting your app and then doing a clean/build on your code.

Comment: I did it before. I'm using an iphone instead the simulator

Comment: is it important the .h is      @interface Map : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate> {?

Comment: Are you putting this code in your custom View Controller? didFinishLaunching should be in the UIApplicationDelegate! That's why it isn't being called....

Comment: do you have implemented - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunching && didFinishLaunchingWithOptions both the methods? then only implement didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and put all your code of didfinishlaunching in this method.

Comment: I only have didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, the code above is the all code for this method

Comment: In your main.m do you return you appdelegate class?        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

This should be implemented in your `UIApplicationDelegate`, not in your `UIViewController`. If you have it in your `UIViewController`, it will never get called. Take the code out of there and put it in your `UIApplicationDelegate` instead.